.NET 8 Isolated Azure Function emits an error RequestTimedOut even with TimeOut configured in host.json
I have a .NET 8.0 Azure Function with a HTTP trigger running in isolated mode. I have set the timeout in host.json to 30 minutes and the function runs for approximately 14 minutes. I am running the function locally.
The function runs fine, but when it returns (after completing) it throws a timeout error (after "return response" and the function exits - see below function code):

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
Functions.RunHttp. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc: Failed to
proxy request with ForwarderError: RequestTimedOut.

This appears to be coming from the runtime - maybe related to the HTTP request (HttpClient?) exceeding the default timeout. Any ideas on what I should do to resolve or where to set the HttpClient timeout? I am considering shifting it to a Durable function but that feels like a bigger change than needed.
Host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functions": [ "RunHttp", "RunTimer" ],
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00",
  "applicationInsights": {
    "samplingSettings": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "excludedTypes": "Request"
    }
  }
}

This is the function:
public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunHttp(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req, 
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    _logger = executionContext.GetLogger<MyClass>();
    await ProcessOrdData(_logger);

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    await response.WriteStringAsync("RunHttp: Function exited successfully");

    return response;
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()

    // Configure logging here for Entity Framework to remove logging all SQL queries.
    .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.Warning);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Error (post function completion).


Can you please share the code for ProcessOrdData

That is customer specific code that I would prefer not to share, it contains several API calls to services and business logic. It runs for 12-15 minutes, and runs flawlessly. This error is surfacing well after that code is executed, after the function completes in full, i.e. post return response.

I'm running into the exact same thing on .net 8 isolated on 3 different timers.

I think your problem is different to mine @Dylan - mine was due to the http timeout limit. If you are using a timer function you should be ok (since this is what I eventually adopted to solve the problem), you may be the a consumption plan limit of 10 mins time out on any function - consider using durable functions or switching to app service plan for your function hosting.

I'm using a premium plan. The timer should run for about 10 seconds. But it will randomly just never report back and say that the timer ran for over 30 minutes, even though it either never ran the code or ran for like 10 seconds.

I'd recommend rethinking your architecture. For example, make the HttpTrigger just do a quick insert into an Azure Queue, and then have a QueueTrigger function pick up that queue item and do the heavy lifting of running your ProcessOrdData. It's nothing to do with Azure, but rather that HTTP isn't intended for long-running operations. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/best-practices?view=aspnetcore-8.0#complete-long-running-tasks-outside-of-http-requests for more info. If you're interested, I can write you an example as an answer?

Thanks @AndrewB - feel free to write an example that I can accept, I was trying to minimise the impact to code that was working fine pre-isolated mode conversion - we deal with millions of lines, and indeed, not all perfect. Durable functions support a HTTP 202 Async pattern which is a familiar technique for us, and did the job in the end, but with more refactoring than I wanted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-features?tabs=csharp

Sounds great, well done. To be honest, it'd probably be more useful you writing your own Durable Function solution here, as an example for people to look at! Don't worry about accepting an answer from me.

We have the same issue with Http-trigger Azure function, after migrating from .NET6 to .NET8 Isolated mode, the azure function starts having timeout exception.
We updated the packages to the latest versions, but still it happens.
Were you able to fix it ? @MurrayFoxcroft

Answering my own question here, we finally just bit the bullet on this and several similar functions implementations, and converted to the "proper" way of performing long running HTTP initiated activities through durable functions and then polling/webhooking for the response, following the below pattern:
Orchestrator with an HTTP trigger and long running actvity function.
public static class StartOrchestrator
{
    [FunctionName("StartOrchestrator")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("MyOrchestrator", null);

        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }
}

Check the response
curl -X GET "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/some_instance_id?taskHub=YourTaskHubName&connection=Storage&code=YourFunctionKey"

Status response - Running, Completed, Failed, Canceled, etc.
{
  "instanceId": "d1234567890c",
  "runtimeStatus": "Running",
  "input": null,
  "customStatus": null,
  "output": null,
  "createdTime": "2021-10-01T12:34:56Z",
  "lastUpdatedTime": "2021-10-01T12:35:56Z"
}

